# How can I fix this wrong result in matrix for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I want to enter in R the following matrix (transition probability) but something I make wrong and the output is not right.
The matrix is in the picture :[image]

my effort is the following :

```
n=100
A = matrix(c(0),n+1,n+1);A
A[1,2] = 1/4 
A[1,1] = 3/4
A[2,1] = 1/4 
A[2,2] = 1/2 
A[2,1] = 1/4
for (k in 2:n) {
  A[k,k+1] = 1/4
  A[k,k]   = 1/2 
  A[k,k-1] = 1/6 
  A[k,k-2] = 1/12
  A[n,n]   = 3/4 
  A[n,n-1] = 1/6 
  A[n,n-2] = 1/12}
A


pA = A
for (i in 10000){
  pA = pA %*% A }
pA
```

but the resulting columns (first 3 columns) must be: 0.2087, 0.1652, 0.1307

Any help?

Comment: `i in 10000` is just `i <- 10000`. Did you miss `1:`?

Comment: In your first lines, you set values for `A[2, ...]` but in your `for`-loop you replace them. For example: `A[2,1] <- 1/4` but for `k = 2` you set `A[2, 1] <- 1/6`.

Comment: @MartinGal because R starts from 1 not from 0.How differently can I insert these probabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a slightly different approach here:

```r
n <- 100
A <- matrix(0, n + 1, n + 1)

# create index for the diagonal and the "other" diagonales
A_diag <- matrix(c(1:(n + 1), 1:(n + 1)), ncol = 2)
A_diag_1 <- matrix(c(1:(n + 1), 1 + 1:(n + 1)), ncol = 2)
A_diag_minus_1 <- matrix(c(1:(n + 1), - 1 + 1:(n + 1)), ncol = 2)
A_diag_minus_2 <- matrix(c(1:(n + 1), - 2 + 1:(n + 1)), ncol = 2)

# populate those diagonales
A[A_diag] <- 1/2
A[A_diag_1[A_diag_1[,2] <= n + 1,]] <- 1/4
A[A_diag_minus_1[A_diag_minus_1[,2] >= 1,]] <- 1/6
A[A_diag_minus_2[A_diag_minus_2[,2] >= 1,]] <- 1/12

# create starting values
A[1, 1] <- 3/4
A[2, 1] <- 1/4

# calculate pA
pA <- A
for (i in 1:10000){ pA <- pA %*% A }
```

This returns

```r
pA[1, 1:3]
#> [1] 0.2087122 0.1651514 0.1306823
```

For the calulation of `pA` you could use the `expm` package to speed things up:

```r
library(expm)

pB <- A %^% 10000

pB[1,1:3]
#> [1] 0.2087122 0.1651514 0.1306823
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for your contribution.Clear and meaningful answer.I appreciate that